# JSON values to String values

Tags: python, json, parsing

Need to convert the below JSON to a strictly string quoted valued JSON using Python. Is there a python "json" module method that I can make use of, or is there a simpler parsing code that I can use to achieve this.

From :

```
data = '[{"id":334,"type":"C","raw":{"field_val":11}}]'
=>      [
          {
            "id":334,
            "type":"C",
            "raw":{
                    "field_val":11
                  }  
          }
        ]
```

To:

```
'[{"id":"334","type":"C","raw":{"field_val":"11"}}]'
```

Comment: The "from" value isn't JSON.

Comment: how did you get `from` string ? Maybe you should use `json` module to generate `from` string.

Comment: What is `C` supposed to be?

Comment: It was an sample/dummy string I was trying to parse. I have corrected my example after looking at my actual data. I have field values where some are missing quotes. I need to add quotes for a dependent library to function.

Comment: Please double check the format of the `from` data since this is neither valid json nor string-formatted json. If this is the given format is correct I would suggest doing some weird string or regex operations instead of using the `json` module.

Comment: You could build a new dictionary that converts all values to strings from the other one, though for the raw field, for example, it's already a string, so you're quoting is mismatched in your example

Comment: Doesn't `json.dumps(from)` work for you ?

Comment: I've corrected again. Primarily I'm looking the following JSON {"key":value} to be converted to {"key":"value"} using json library. Should be applicable for any nested json too.

Comment: Like I said, build a new dictionary. If you want to do with nested json, you'll need to do it recursively

Comment: with `json` lib : `json.load(data)` or with `ast` lib : `ast.literal_eval(data)`

Comment: I tried json.loads(data) and ast.literal_eval(data) .. Both do not server my purpose.. I still get the following output: {u'key': 123}
{'key': 123}  for the input: {"key": 123}.. I'm looking for {"key": "123"}

Answer (score 0):

The json module is what you want.

```
import json

string = '''[
          {
            "id":334,
            "type":"C",
            "raw":{
                    "field_val":11
                  }  
          }
        ]'''

myList = json.loads(string)
print(myList)
```

The output is:

```
[{u'raw': {u'field_val': 11}, u'type': u'C', u'id': 334}]
```

Then you can use json.dumps():

```
print(json.dumps(myList,))
```

Output:

```
'[{"raw": {"field_val": 11}, "type": "C", "id": 334}]'
```

And if you want the indentation:

```
print(json.dumps(myList, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "raw": {
            "field_val": 11
        }, 
        "type": "C", 
        "id": 334
    }
]
```